# Mongodb is there a way to mix inclusion and exclusion in a projection or similar?

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following document representing a user:

```
{
  first_name: 'john',
  last_name: 'doe',
  address: {
    street: 'something',
    city: 'New York',
    etc: '...'
  },
  resume: {
    full_text: 'very long text containing the whole resume...',
    position: 'superhero',
    experience: '5 years',
    etc: '...'
  },
  gender: 'male'
}
```

I want to retrieve everything at the root but gender, for the address, I only want the city, and for the resume, I want everything but the full_text property.

Intuitively I would want to write the following projection:

```
{
  gender: 0,
  address: {
    city: 1
  },
  resume: {
    full_text: 0
  }
}
```

However, I cannot mix inclusive and exclusive projections, so is there a way to achieve a similar result with MongoDB, or do I have to do this by hand?

Also, it is worth mentioning that I am not in control of the content of the address and resume, their properties may change. What will never change is that I only want the city for the address and I want everything but full_text for the resume.

Any advice on the best way to handle this is highly appreciated.

Comment: try addfield and unset if aggregation pipeline used

Answer (score 1):

A `$project` stage removes all fields (apart from the `_id` field), i.e. you get only the fields for `1` plus the `_id` field - unless you explicitly disable it.

You can use `$addFields` or `$set`, which is an alias for `$addFields`.

If you like to remove fields, then use either `$unset` or `$$REMOVE` variable.

However, your example is a bit more difficult, because you ask for nested objects. You could use `$filter` on it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      gender: "$$REMOVE",
      address: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$address" },
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.k", "city" ] }
          }
        }
      },
      resume: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$resume" },
            cond: { $ne: [ "$$this.k", "full_text" ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/54EfCY1Rcnb)